# Java Memory issue while executing sbt package in spark

Tags: java, sbt, apache-spark

Can you please suggest me solution for the below issues.

hduser@hduser-VirtualBox:/usr/local/spark1/project$ sbt package
**OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000a8000000, 1073741824, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)**
#

## There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.

## Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 1073741824 bytes for committing reserved memory.

## An error report file with more information is saved as:

## /usr/local/spark-1.1.0-bin-hadoop1/project/hs_err_pid26824.log

hduser@hduser-VirtualBox:/usr/local/spark1/project$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.3) (7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to run with quite a large Java heap size (1GB). I'd start by reducing that. If you really do need that much, you might be in trouble: it looks as though your machine just doesn't have enough RAM to allocate it for you.